# Hadoop file upload through python-cgi

Tags: python, hadoop

Is there any way to upload a file to HDFS through a python-cgi based web page?

I was planning on getting it through a form based file input and then pass the /path/to/file to the Hadoop command. But browser security doesn't give you access to the filepath.

I'm looking for something a little more efficient than letting the user enter the filepath.

Comment: Does the machine where you are running the Python script have access to the Hadoop cluster? What do you mean by _browser security_? Couldn't you pass the Hdfs path as a variable in that form and then have the Python script (which is probably running in your server) saving the file in the Hdfs?

Comment: Yes. The machine is part of the cluster. I tried uploading the file using a html form to get the filepath. But the browser apparently restricts that. So you only get the filename. Not the path.

Comment: Then I would add the path you wanna save it in to the Form and take a look to https://hdfscli.readthedocs.io/en/latest/